# How to use html string to open browser in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open the phone's browser to show my html string.
Now my codes are:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(htmlString);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But it meets an error:

***android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=...***

where dat is my html string.

So how can I correctly open the browser?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45785084/2979171 use Chrome tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(htmlString);
```

HTML is not a `Uri`.

> So how can I correctly open the browser?

Step #1: Write the HTML to a file on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getCacheDir()`)

Step #2: Set up `FileProvider` to serve files from the directory that you used in step #1

Step #3: Use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` for your `File` that you used in step #1

Step #4: Use that `Uri` in your `Intent`, also adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` before calling `startActivity()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this way but when I open the browser, it open the url which is my storage path instead of the html file.My codes are: Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "myprovideranth", file);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
        browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);       this.grantUriPermission("myprovider",uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: @WeihengLian: What does "it open the url which is my storage path instead of the html file" mean? Other than having `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` (which should not be needed here AFAIK), what you have seems fine. Note that not all Web browsers will support the `content` scheme that your `Uri` will have. Android's expectation is that you would use `WebView` in your app to view this content, not try to load it into a third-party Web browser -- Android does not handle your scenario very well.

Comment: I mean when I open the browser, it tells me that it can not resolve the url. I find that this "url" is the storage path of my html file. Now I'm doing something about api auth, so I cannot use webview.

Comment: @WeihengLian: "I find that this "url" is the storage path of my html file." -- it should be the result of `FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "myprovideranth", file)`. That will be something of the form `content://your.authority.string.here/your-name-here/otherstuff/file.html`, where `your.authority.string.here` is the `android:authorities` value, `your-name-here` is what you put in the `name` of the element in your `FileProvider` metadata XML resource, and `otherstuff/file.html` will depend on details of the `File` that you passed into `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: @WeihengLian: "Now I'm doing something about api auth, so I cannot use webview" -- it is unlikely that you can use a Web browser for that either.

Comment: @CommansWare You are exactly right. Do I misunderstand your words? I don't really know how to solve it. Can you tell me in detail? Thank you very much.

Comment: @CommansWare I have to use a browser because when I use webview, google tells me it only supports browsers for authorization

Comment: @WeihengLian: You may want to discuss this with the server maintainers and see if there is a better authentication option that you can pursue. I do not know where this HTML is coming from. If you are scraping it from a Web server, that HTML may be useless. For example, a third-party Web browser will not have the expected referrer URL, session cookies, etc. that the Web server might expect when the user does whatever is necessary with that rendered HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I need to talk with the server maintainer